# How can I detect all the capital letters in a string given by the user?

Tags: java, algorithm

So I'm trying to write a method where it detects all the capital letters given by the user. How is this possible? Is it possible to do it using ASCII values? Is it possible in another way? Please give me suggestions and about the best way to come up with this algorithm

NOTE: problem is as stated at bottom of the source CODE

**SOURCE CODE**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private String userPassword;
private char[] passChar;
private int passwordScore = 0;

public String getPassword(){
    userPassword = sc.nextLine();
    passChar = userPassword.toCharArray();
    return userPassword;
}
// Ingore this comment below, this is just for me
//do for( char i : passChar.length) or actualy if statmen so that if the pass is not 8 charaters long it doesnt qulafiy
public void passRequirments(){

}

public int passLength(){     
    for(char upperCase: passChar){          
        passwordScore = passwordScore + 4;     
    }

    return passwordScore;
 }


//THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING TROUBLE 
public void passUpper(){        
    for (char c : passChar){          
        if (Character.isUpperCase(passChar.charAt(c))){
        }
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

```
public void passUpper(){ 
      for (char c : passChar){      
          if (Character.isUpperCase(passChar.charAt(c))){
              passwordScore =  passwordScore + ((userPassword.length()- passChar.charAt(c)) * 2);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Right.  You showed us "where" you are having trouble.  Twice.  And if I may ask, what is the precise nature of the trouble that you are having?

Comment: Alright I edited "the problem" code, and its where at passChar.charAt(c) gives me an error. which is  Cannot invoke charAt(char) on the array type char[]

Comment: Why are you calling `passChar.charAt(c)`? `c` is your `char`. You're using a `for-each` loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I realized my mistake but not sure what to do next

Comment: Hey Ibrahim, basically you want your method to receive a string a input and it should print out all the capital letters present in a string right, this is what you want ?

Comment: "...what to do next": you mean next after replacing uses of `passChar.charAt(c)` with just `c`?

Comment: @zenwraight correct, but the string should be an input from a user. So thats what I want

Comment: @KevinAnderson I mean I want to print out all the capatial letters how is that possible ?

Comment: Hey Ibrahim did you tried the approach that I have posted below ?

Comment: @IbrahimAyyoub I think you've chosen the right (clean) approach to the problem. All you have to do is just count the number of upper case letters in the loop (just put counter++ in there) and calculate the score change afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could be a feasible solution

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main{


      public static int printUpperCaseLetters(String s)
      {
        char[] ch = new char[s.length()];
        ch = s.toCharArray();
        int cap_count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++)
        {
          int val = (int)ch[i];
          if(val>=65 && val<=90)
          {
            cap_count++;
            System.out.println(ch[i]);
          }
        }
        return cap_count;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.next();
        // So this method returns you the capital letters count inside of the string
        int cap_count = printUpperCaseLetters(s);
      }
    }
```

Hope this help!

You can fetch the function part and add it to your code.

Just focus on the method printUpperCaseLetters and pass your String to this method.

Comment: Heey, I tried it , and it works, but how can i check how many capatil letters are there? like setting it to int ? I need to do (length-n) * 2 where n is the number of capatial letters

Comment: I have updated my answer that should return you with count of capital letters.

Comment: Btw you could do directly ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z', no conversion to int needed and easier to read, but doesn't work for &Auml; (Ä) or other foreign characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex to replace all non capital letters to empty space:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
```

You will end up with string that contains only capital letters from input.